# JSON keys for x axis, values for y

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Basically, I am trying to recreate this graph which was created in Excel:

[image]

My code so far is this...

```
    var theData = [
      {
        'FB':4,
        'Mv':4,
        'CB':5,
        'SL':3,
        'CH':2,
        'OT':2,
        'Ctrl':6,
        'Cmd':6,
        'Del':5,
        'AA':6,
       },
      {
        'FB':2,
        'Mv':3,
        'CB':4,
        'SL':5,
        'CH':4,
        'OT':3,
        'Ctrl':5,
        'Cmd':6,
        'Del':6,
        'AA':5,
       },
       etc...
    ];

    var margin = {top:10, right:10, bottom:30, left:40},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.keys(theData[0]))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([2,8])
        .range([height,0]);

    var xAx = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
    var yAx = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient('left')
        .ticks(3);

    var svgContainer = d3.select('#d3Stuff').append('svg')
        .attr('width',width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height',height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style('border','1px solid black')
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svgContainer.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAx)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", -6)
        .style("text-anchor", "end");

    svgContainer.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAx)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

I'm having problems trying to get circles to appear for the values in the data object. I would like them to line up with the x axis keys, obviously. If I can at least get the initial values to show, I can calculate the min/max/avg later.

Here is what the code creates so far:

[image]

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ordinal scale to find the x position of any circle using the key (since the ordinal domain is made up of keys). For example `x("FB")`, `x("Mv")`, etc.

To create the circles, you need to bind to an array, in the typical d3 fashion, using the enter, update, exit stuff.

Since your data is a hash, not an array, you need to first get it into an array form. That's easy using `d3.map()` with `theData` (I'd recommend removing the array `[]` wrapping around the hash inside `theData`, since it doesn't do anything, but still):

```
d3.map(theData[0]).entries()
/* returns [
  {
    "key": "FB",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": "Mv",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": "CB",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "key": "SL",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "key": "CH",
    "value": 2
  },
  ...
]"
```

Once you have this associative array, you can do the usual `data(...)` binding, append the circles, and then position them with something like

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key); })
```

Comment: Actually the data is more than what I posted, more objects in the array:

[{
   'FB':4,
   'Mv':4,
   'CB':5,
   'SL':3,
   'CH':2,
   'OT':2,
   'Ctrl':6,
   'Cmd':6,
   'Del':5,
   'AA':6,
 },
{
   'FB':3,
   'Mv':2,
   'CB':3,
   'SL':4,
   'CH':5,
   'OT':5,
   'Ctrl':7,
   'Cmd':5,
   'Del':4,
   'AA':3,
 }, etc...
]

I will have to calculate the min/max/avg for all these too